# Android hdpi resource load problem

Tags: android, hdpi

good day
we are developing game for android and have some trouble with resource loading on high dpi devices.

our resources are located in res/drawable directory
on a standart dpi device the game work properly, but on hdpi (tested on HTC Desire) all resources which located in res/drawable-hdpi load are loaded correctly, but the resources which miss in drawable-hdpi directory but present in res/drawable are ignored

but everything works fine on the virtual device with hdpi.

does anybody encounter this problem and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from non device tester advice here, can You move those missing resources to drawable/nodpi if that does not conflicts your development strategy ?

Don't know to what extent it will work, but u can try!